# Create Multi Part Tar Archives

Tags: tar

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop and I use rsync to back up my hard disk to my external and make a monthly tar.gz of the files.  Unfortunately, my new online storage offers more space, but has a maximum upload size of 20G.

Question:

How can I convert/change the following tar command so that it produces multiple, connected archives of 19 GB and writes to my log:

```
tar cvpzf /media/user/external/post-rsync-home-files-only-tars/home-files-only-backup.$(date +"%F").tgz  /media/user/external/home-files-only >> /usr/local/bin/my_logs/post-rsync-home-files-only-tars.log
```

Currently, the above creates 1 archive ~60GB...   Goal is to create three 19GB archives plus one 3GB, so that I well inside upload limits..

(fyi, these are long-term storage archives, that hopefully, I will never need, so ease of creation and extraction are my priority concerns... I have read some entirely too complex solutions to similar problems)

I have tried this solution:

```
tar -cvpzf - /media/user/external/home-files-only | split --bytes=19G --suffix-length=2 --numeric-suffix - /media/user/external/home-files-only-multipart.$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%m).tar.gz
```

but my rookie skills, I have not been able to successfully write to log log file, nor have I extracted the archive using:

```
cat home-files-only-multipart.<date>.tar.gz | tar xzvf -
```

What am I missing on the extraction?

Is there a better solution?

How to write to log?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at `-M`?

Comment: @barrycarter thx your tip, helped me figure out my extraction problem.. tar doesn't support compressed multi-volume archives, so I have been creating "mutant" archives that can't be extracted... whoops.

Comment: You might also look at [duplicity](https://duplicity.gitlab.io/) which makes incremental backups to a remote server, and can take a max volume size.